# How to check os(visionOS) on Flutter

Tags: flutter, visionos

**<Updated 11/20>**
[image]
I remove the destination device `Apple Vision Pro (designed for iPad)` and add `Apple Vision` which SDK is `visionOS`, then I click Build and the project show **No such module 'Flutter'**. That is also the right result due to Flutter currently not support visionOS?

===

I try to do [Isolate features that are unavailable in visionOS](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/visionos/bringing-your-app-to-visionos/#Isolate-features-that-are-unavailable-in-visionOS) with my code in Flutter, and I wrote a Flutter plugin to check if os is visionOS:

```swift
#if os(visionOS) 
    return true
#elseif os(iOS)
    return false
#else
    return false
#endif
```

I run `flutter run` to run my app in the iOS simulator for Flutter building the iOS native code. After that, I open Xcode beta and run the "runner" project in "Apple Vision Pro (designed for iPad)" simulator.

But it always runs into the line `#elseif os(iOS)`

Which step did I go wrong?

Comment: By Joseph Mambwe https://twitter.com/MrMambwe/status/1672339427136249857

It needs to compile flutter as a framework using these instructions, then add it to an existing visionOS project (Option B)
https://docs.flutter.dev/add-to-app/ios/project-setup

Answer (score 1):

You haven't done anything wrong; that's the correct behavior. `"Apple Vision Pro (designed for iPad)"` is a mode where apps built for iOS are being run as-is on visionOS. `os(visionOS)` will only be true if you build against the visionOS SDK instead, which [is not currently possible with Flutter](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/128313) (unless you build a custom Flutter engine against visionOS and modify the `flutter` tool locally).

The page you linked to is specifically about building against the visionOS SDK rather than running apps built against the iOS SDK on visionOS, so isn't currently relevant for Flutter.

Comment: I think you are right that the conditional statement is done during compile time. Since `flutter run` run as iOS app, there is no runtime option to run the #elseif os(visionOS).

Comment: You don't have to take my word for it, the fact that it's compile time is clearly documented: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/statements/#Conditional-Compilation-Block